# How to check the availability for the internal app services hosted inside internal App Service Environment

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-availability-set

I am trying to setup the availability test (URL-Ping test) in Azure Application Insights, but the endpoint that requires the basic authentication. And the endpoint(Azure App Services) resides in internal App Service Environment (ASE).

So, can anyone suggest me how to check the availability for the internal azure app services hosted inside internal App Service Environment.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late the response, but here it goes.

Please have a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability#create-a-url-ping-test) that explains how to do it. Basically you need to configure rules on your NSG to allow inbound traffic from your Application Insights instance.

> If your URL is not visible from the public internet, you can choose to selectively open up your firewall to allow only the test transactions through. To learn more about the firewall exceptions for our availability test agents, consult the IP address guide.