# Is it possible to configure ApplicationInsights 's AvailabilityTests for an end point (of AppService) hosted in ASE?

Tags: azure, ase, appinsights

We have a requirement to configure Availability Tests (URL Ping Test) on an End Point (App Service) which is hosted inside App Service Environment (ASE).

I don't think it would be possible. but, I might be wrong. Any comments on this or point me to the proper docs?

i have see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680671/how-to-check-the-availability-for-the-internal-app-services-hosted-inside-intern) but it is not properly answered.

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability#create-a-url-ping-test) that explains how to do it. Basically you need to configure rules on your NSG to allow inbound traffic from your Application Insights instance.

> If your URL is not visible from the public internet, you can choose to selectively open up your firewall to allow only the test transactions through. To learn more about the firewall exceptions for our availability test agents, consult the IP address guide.